# User defined type as reference

Tags: nim-lang

Are these two definitions equivalent?

```
type
  PersonObj = object
    name: string
    age: int
  PersonRef = ref PersonObj

type
  PersonObj = ref object
    name: string
    age: int
```

In the latter should PersonObj be simply called Person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not equivalent as the first `PersonObj` is not `ref`, while the second is. To be equivalent the second definition should read as

```
type PersonRef = ref object
  name: string
  age: int
```

Now `Obj` or `Ref` suffixes is your own decision. Usually the suffixes are not used if the type is intended to be always used either as value type or a ref type, so it would be just:

```
type Person = ref object
  name: string
  age int
```

Comment: I think the question was whether the original `PersonRef` is equivalent to the second definition of `PersonObj`.